# Existence of an inverse to the Schwarz-Christoffel mapping

Tags: cv.complex-variables, conformal-maps

As an elementary result in complex analysis, one can use the argument principle to show that the Schwarz-Christoffel transform is injective on the interior of the polygon to which it maps. Could this one-to-one correspondence be used to show that such an inverse mapping exists for at least a subset of the upper half-plane? In my search for an answer, I found page 24 of the following [paper](https://fse.studenttheses.ub.rug.nl/8761/1/Willem_Hendriks_WB_2009.pdf) that mentions the existence of a trigonometric inverse for a mapping to a bar-shaped region. Does a generalization of this result hold? More specifically, has existing literature produced an inverse formula for any polygonal geometry?

I should also hope to refer anyone curious about the existence and Holder continuity of an inverse to the following [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352430/inverse-of-the-schwartz-christoffel-map-and-the-continuity?rq=1).

Thank you all.

[image: Inverse Schwarz-Christoffel Mapping]

Comment: Schwarz-Christoffel map is not always injective. When it is injective, the inverse map (from its image to the upper half-plane) of course exists. So what is your question exactly? This inverse map is sometimes an elementary function, as in your example. In most cases it is not.

Comment: Is there a general formula that could work for all polygonal geometries? Do you know of one?

Comment: @JPwin, no, there's in general no explicit formula in terms of elementary functions. For example, for rectangles you can write a formula using elliptic functions, for triangles, the Schwarz-Cristoffel map gives you a hypergeometric function (and the inverse is rather obscure function)

Comment: What do you mean by a "general formula" and formula for what? Schwarz-Christoffel map IS a formula. Are you asking whether the map or its inverse is an elementary function or what? Or conditions under which it is injective? Can you state your question precisely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a general answer for your question, but I would be very excited to learn more about this topic.  Even having more examples would be very interesting. Here is what I do know.

In the forward direction - from the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ to the polygon $P$.  If $P$ is a triangle, then the SC map is basically given by the Beta function.  If $P$ is a regular $n$-gon, the SC map can given in terms of a hypergeometric function.  See Exercise 5.19 of the paper "Mappings to polygonal domains" in the book "Explorations in complex analysis".

In the backwards direction - from $P$ to $\mathbb{H}$.  If $P$ is a "rational" triangle (all angles are rational multiples of $\pi$) then it may be unfolded to give a quadratic differential $q_P$ on a Riemann surface $X_P$.  (The unfolding procedure comes from the theory of billiards.)  The inverse to the SC map is then, by the Schwarz reflection principle, a branched covering from $X_P$ to the Riemann sphere. In the presence of symmetries this covering map can have pretty expressions.

I carefully understood this covering map in two cases beyond the trigonometric example.  When $P$ is a square or a hexagon we treat it as the unfolding of a rational triangle $Q$.  We deduce that $X_Q$ is a square or hexagonal torus.  Thus the covering map is the Weierstrass $\wp$-function for the square and hexagonal lattices, respectively.  We can express these (as usual) in terms of theta functions

**Remarks**:

When $P$ is a rectangle then a similar discussion holds - this case is discussed in the BSc thesis you link to.

When $P$ is rational, the covering map lifts to give an automorphic map from $\tilde{X}_P$ (the universal cover) to $\mathbb{H}$. This will have a Poincaré series.  But Poincaré series have very poor convergence properties, so I don't really regard this as an "answer".

When $P$ is not rational, I don't see how to proceed... It would be nice to have "non-existence results", but I don't know what those would look like.